# Blank page when publishing Angular 5 + .NET Core Web API

Tags: .net, angular, iis, asp.net-core

I tried to publish an Angular 5 app and a .NET Core Web Api to the same server (IIS with .NET Core bundle), however when I start it up, it just shows a blank page (no console errors or log errors).
The Web API works (tested with postman), so I'm guessing it might be a routing issue.
The angular 5 app is a fresh one created with Angular-Cli and build to production using

`ng build --prod` and then copied the content of the dist folder over into wwwroot

The .NET Core Web Api is also a fresh API with just a basic GET request, published using:

```
dotnet publish --self-contained -r win-x64 -c Release
```

and then copied the content into wwwroot, which means all of angular files and .net core files are in same directory. I haven't touched the web.config.

If I only publish the angular app it works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can use `ng build --prod -op wwwroot` to build ng app in wwwroot folder and then configure routing like https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-fix-the-routing-225ac90f

Answer (score 0):

Go to the index.html of your published angular app and find

```
<base href="/">
```

Change it to

```
<base href="">
```

Comment: Apparently when it builds the angular application, it puts all the files in the root.